# Not able to create hello world program using Grails 3.1.3 or Grails 2.5.4

Tags: grails-2.5, grails-3.1

My project is based on Grails 2.2.2. Now I need to upgrade to Grails 2.5.4 in order to upgrade Groovy version 2.4.4

Hence, I downloaded Grails 2.5.4 and set up the Grails Home in environment variable and bin folder in class path.

From command line I can see grails -version is Grails 2.5.4

Next, I created grails create-app helloworld. It got created successfully.

Did `cd` into helloworld project and tried to run grails run-app.

after this, on command line I can see Configuring classpath for around 10-15 mins and ultimately I get error that `tomcat:7.0.55.3 not found`. 
In grails 2.5.4 directory I see tomcat version 7.0.55.2 so in `BuildConfig.groovy` I changed tomcat to version 7.0.55.2 . and again ran grails run-app this time plugin got installed.

Next I got error for

```
    ':cache:1.1.8'       
   ":asset-pipeline:2.5.7"
```

I am surprised that these are there in plugins folder for Grails 2.5.4 but still it complains.

I added maven repo to

> ```
> mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins" 
> mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
> ```

But this did not worked.

I copied this manually and ran run-app again then I got error for dependencies related to cache and asset-pipeline.

I commented out this and did run-app . 
Next I got error that catalina libraries not found. Then I copied libraries related to tomcat but still not able to run hello world project. I got error Spring parserContext class not found.

Earlier, when I was working on Grails 2.2.2 I did not had such problems and was able to create and run helloworld project within no time.

Now with Grails 2.5.4 and Grails 3.1.3 I am really frustrated. 
I even tried Grails 2.4.4 and Grails 3.0.3.

Can any one guide me as to how I can create and run helloworld grails project with Grails version 2.5.4 or Grails 3.1.3 . 
I am also ready to try with older Grails version which has Groovy 2.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

I added proxy settings to BuildConfig.groovy file and it worked.